# Webservice Performance

Tags: c#, .net

I have a couple of load balanced application server running on IIS 7. I need to check how many webservice calls are made from each of the server. I also need to check this at a particular instance. Do we have some thing in .net which communicates with both the server and gives me the snapshot at a particular instance.
Thanks

Comment: made from or Made to?  if it is "made to" then Jeff's suggestion would work as would just grabbing the IIS logs however if it is "made from" you will need to come up with another scheme like logging all the calls or publishing your own custom performance counter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Perfmon to add statistics regarding the number of calls. Once you're doing that you could also add timing data as well... You can then use Perfmon on the local box or hook up to it remotely with any number of tools.

Sorry I can't point you to specifics -- I've only seen it done, not done it myself :) But I think it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

And some sample code, showing how you could implement performance counters:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace TEST
{
    // sample implementation
    public static class PerformanceHelper
    {
        // update a performance counter value
        public static void UpdateCounter(string WebMethodName, int count)
        {
            // to be able to turn the monitoring on or off
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PerformanceMonitor"].ToUpper() == "TRUE")
            {
                PerformanceCounter counter;
                if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("SAMPLE"))
                {
                    CounterCreationDataCollection listCounters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
                    CounterCreationData newCounter = new CounterCreationData(WebMethodName, WebMethodName, PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64);
                    listCounters.Add(newCounter);
                    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("SAMPLE", "DESCRIPTION", new PerformanceCounterCategoryType(), listCounters);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(WebMethodName, "SAMPLE"))
                    {
                        CounterCreationDataCollection rebuildCounterList = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
                        CounterCreationData newCounter = new CounterCreationData(WebMethodName, WebMethodName, PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64);
                        rebuildCounterList.Add(newCounter);
                        PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("SAMPLE");
                        foreach (var item in category.GetCounters())
                        {
                            CounterCreationData existingCounter = new CounterCreationData(item.CounterName, item.CounterName, item.CounterType);
                            rebuildCounterList.Add(existingCounter);
                        }
                        PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete("SAMPLE");
                        PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("SAMPLE", "DESCRIPTION", new PerformanceCounterCategoryType(), rebuildCounterList);
                    }
                }
                counter = new PerformanceCounter("SAMPLE", WebMethodName, false);
                if (count == -1)
                    counter.IncrementBy(-1);
                else
                    counter.IncrementBy(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks stackuser however it this will not solve the problem where I need to get the stats from both the server

Comment: It definitely gives you the building blocks to modify your web service to gather the required information. In the performance monitor you can combine load data about the cpu for exmample, and combine this with your own measurements. The code above is just a sample on the web service part.